# Program that displays the nth roots of unity (C programming)

Tags: c

I have to write program that displays the nth roots of unity when given a positive integer n. It's a programming project 27.4 from K.N.King book on C programming.

my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
int n, k;
double complex nth;

printf("Enter positive integer: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
  nth = exp(2 * M_PI * I * k / n);
  printf("k = %d, %g + %g\n", k, creal(nth), cimag(nth));
}

return 0;
}
```

No matter what value of n I pass results are always the same. Can you give me some tips?

Comment: you should try using a `double`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exp` function expects a `double`, but you pass it a `double complex`.

Use `cexp` instead:

```
nth = cexp(2 * M_PI * I * k / n);
```

Output:

```
Enter positive integer: 5
k = 0, 1 + 0
k = 1, 0.309017 + 0.951057
k = 2, -0.809017 + 0.587785
k = 3, -0.809017 + -0.587785
k = 4, 0.309017 + -0.951057
```

Comment: @M.Chelm Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.